# Unbalanced tree - JS Error

Tags: javascript

I am developing an application that uses loops to create a desired output; here from number 1 to 50. I am using a for loop and uses the concatenation method to show the looped numbers. But then the debugger in the browser is saying that I have written an unbalanced tree.
Here is the error:

> An unbalanced tree was written using document.write() causing data from the network to be reparsed. For more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  for(i=1;i<=50;i++){
    document.write("<a href='page.html#"+i+">"+i+"</a>");
  }
</script>
```

**Note:** The links I am creating use an id attribute to link somewhere exactly on the page.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Looks like the message is caused by a missing single closing quote.

Answer (score 2):

It's a warning. It happens in Firefox 4 and later.

From [MDN: Optimizing your pages for speculative parsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Optimizing_your_pages_for_speculative_parsing):

> However, in Firefox 4 and later the HTML parser also runs the HTML tree construction algorithm speculatively. The upside is that when a speculation succeeds, there's no need to reparse the part of the incoming file that was already scanned for scripts, style sheets and images. The downside is that there's more work lost when the speculation fails.
>   [...]
>   Speculative tree building fails when `document.write()` changes the tree builder state such that the speculative state after the `</script>` tag no longer holds when all the content inserted by `document.write()` has been parsed. However, only unusual uses of `document.write()` cause trouble. Here are the things to avoid:
>   [...]
>   **Don't write unbalanced trees. `<script>document.write("<div>");</script>` is bad. `<script>document.write("<div></div>");</script>` is OK.**

The solution is to write the missing single closing quote.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        for(i=1;i<=50;i++){
            document.write("<a href='page.html#"+i+"'>"+i+"</a>");
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed out an single quotes.

Try running with below:

```
for(i=1;i<=50;i++){
    document.write("<a href='page.html#"+i+"'>"+i+"</a><br/>");
}
```

Be careful while using single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you `document.write(...)` a balanced tree, for example `document.write('<span>X</span>')`, then you still can get the same error message.

One possible explanation is that you execute that JS code not in the body but in the head of the html, writing something that cannot occur in the head.

For example:

Wrong:

```
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
        document.write('<span>X</span>');
    </script>
</html>
```

Good:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head> 
    <body>
        <script>
            document.write('<span>X</span>');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```